ERC-20 allowance always 0 after approval
I'm writing a smart contract that transfers ERC-20 tokens from wallet A (sender) to wallet B (receiver) and deducts a fee to wallet C (owner of the contract).
The problem is that when I'm trying to make wallet A approve the smart contract to make the transfer, the allowance stays 0 so the contract token transfer from wallet A to B fails with ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance error.
contract FeeTransfer is Ownable {
    /** Errors */
    error NotApproved();
    error TransferFailed();

    /** Events */
    event Payment (
        address indexed token,
        address indexed sender,
        address indexed destination,
        uint256 amount,
        uint256 fee
    );

    uint8 public feePercentage = 10;

    function setFeePercentage(uint8 newFeePercentage) public onlyOwner {
        feePercentage = newFeePercentage;
    }

    function approve(address token, uint256 amount) public {
        IERC20 tokenInstance = IERC20(token);
        if (!tokenInstance.approve(address(this), amount)) {
            revert NotApproved();
        }
    }

    function payment(address token, address destination, uint256 amount) public {
        IERC20 tokenInstance = IERC20(token);

        if (tokenInstance.allowance(msg.sender, address(this)) < amount) {
            revert NotApproved();
        }

        uint256 fee = (amount * feePercentage) / 100;
        unit256 amountAfterFee = amount - fee;

        if (!tokenInstance.transferFrom(msg.sender, destination, amountAfterFee)) {
            revert TransferFailed();
        }

        if (!tokenInstance.transferFrom(msg.sender, owner(), fee)) {
            revert TransferFailed();
        }

        // Emit event
        emit Payment(token, msg.sender, destination, amount, fee);
    }
}


A very common mistake.
When you are calling the approve function here:
function approve(address token, uint256 amount) public {
        IERC20 tokenInstance = IERC20(token);
        if (!tokenInstance.approve(address(this), amount)) {
            revert NotApproved();
        }
    }

The feeTransfer contract becomes the msg.sender, which means that it approves itself to spend the tokens.
Instead, the wallet should directly call the approve function in the token contract, there's no way around it other than manually calling the approve function, and then calling the payment function.
